# Should I ask this question on WordPress Development or Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, wordpress-se

I am looking for a way to quickly copy changes from the local version of a website to the live one (and/or vise versa). The site is using WordPress and the changes are all done via WordPress' Dashboard, like adding menus and categories, editing plugins and so on.

Currently the way is to copy over the entire website, but that takes a long time. If there is something in WordPress that enables you to export all your settings that I've not found then it would be for WordPress. If the solution doesn't involve WordPress then it would be for Stack Overflow. In order to know where to ask I have to know the solution, but then asking would be pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a general solution and are looking for a solution specific to WordPress I would suggest asking at [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Make sure you search existing questions as I'm certain there will be something that already answers your question. Two examples that may help you:

- [Database synchronization between dev/staging and production](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2100/81652)
- [Moving Site From Development to Production](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/109814/81652)

Searching previous questions tagged [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) should help too.

It's a topic that has been covered a lot so if no previous questions help your specific case make sure clearly explain why in your question.